# Consultar valor en BD desde formulario en Laravel 9

Tags: php, model-view-controller, laravel-9

Estoy haciendo un CRUD el cual ya esta funcionando, lo que necesito ahora es consultar los datos mediante un ID desde un formulario

**View**

````
```
<a href="{{ url('alumnos',[$row]) }}" class="btn btn-warning"></a>
```
````

**Route**

````
```
Route::resource('alumnos', AlumnosController::class);
```
````

**Controller**

```
     public function show(string $id)
        {
            $alumno = alumnos::find($id);
            $carreras = Carreras::all();
            return view ('editAlumno',compact('alumno','carreras'));
        }
```

**Como puedo hacer la comunicacion para enviar la variable rut y consultar en bd**

```
<form class="d-flex" method="POST" action="{{ url('prueba') }}">
    @csrf
    <input class="form-control me-2" name="rutdb" type="search" placeholder="Rut" aria- 
   label="Search">
    <button class="btn btn-outline-success" type="submit">Buscar</button>
</form>
```